# Consider $\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)^4 = 1$ then solve $z^3-3z^2+4z-2=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider $\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)^4=1$ then solve for the roots of $z^3-3z^2+4z-2=0$

First consider $$\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)^4=1$$

Let $$w^4=\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)^4=1$$ $$w^4=1$$

Now work this into its polar form

In cartesian form $w^4=1$ $\rightarrow$ $w^4=1+0i$

Recognize that this is a straight line on the right hand side of the real axis. A triangle with opposite side 0 and adjacent 1.

$$tan^{1}(\theta) = \frac{0}{1}$$ $$\theta=0$$

Also $r = \sqrt{1^2+0^2}=1$

Hence polar form is $$w^4=e^{0i}$$ 
So $$w^4=(e^{0i})$$
Using De moivre's theorem we find that $$(w^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}=w=(e^{0i})^{\frac{1}{4}}$$
$$w=e^{0i}$$

Because we're finding the root to the power of 4 we have 4 answers just like real number. We can find the next 3 answers by $$0+\frac{2\pi k}{4} \space  \space  \space k=0,1,2,3,4 $$

$$\theta = 0, \frac{pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi$$

in which $$w=1,i,-1,-i$$

If  $$w^4=\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)^4$$ $$w=\left(\frac{z-2}{z}\right)=1,i,-1,-i$$

At $w=1$ w is undefined

At $w=i, \space z=\frac{1+i}{2}$

At $w=-1, \space z=1$

At $w=-i, \space z=\frac{1-i}{2}$

I got lost after that

Comment: Is my hint below helpful? If you're trying to prove $z^3-3z^2+4z-2=0$ given $z^4=(z-2)^4$ then the hint is the answer. If you're actually solving $z^3-3z^2+4z-2=0$ then the hint provides the factorisation from which the answer is immmediate: $z=1$, and $z=1\pm i$.

Comment: Hey sorry i meant to say "solve for the roots"

Comment: As I said above, the factorisation would help with that. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $z^4-(z-2)^4=8(z-1)(z^2-2z+2)=8(z^3-3z^2+4z-2).$

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got that if i you expand $w^4$ you get....

$$w^4=\frac{z^4-8z^3+24z^2-32z+16}{z^4}=1$$ $$z^4-8z^3+24z^2-32z+16=z^4$$

$$-8z^3+24z^2-32z+16=z^4-z^4$$ $$-8z^3+24z^2-32z+16=0$$ $$-8(z^3-3z^2+4z-2)=0$$

Hence $z^3-3z^2+4z-2 = 0 = -8w^4$ since constant factors do not affect roots then roots stay the same as with $w^4$ hence $z= 1+i, 1-i, 1$